# Vector from point to point of tangency on a circle

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have two points "A" and "B", one them let's say "B" is the center of a circle with radius "r".
I also have the vector AB, let's call it "d" and a tangent line which contains point A and point of tangency "T".
I'm looking for a vector AT, we can call it "t" that lays on said tangent line.

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbJHd.png)

I know I can easily find the length of vector "t" by trigonometry, but I can't come up (or find) a way to find the vector form [x,y] of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(x,y)$ is the unit vector along $\vec{t}$, then $\vec{t}=(x,y)t$ and $\vec{r}=\vec{TB}=(-y,x)r$. From equation $\vec{d}=\vec{t}+\vec{r}$ you can get $(x,y)$.

Comment: (ok, stackexchange you can stop adding your random texts to my comments)  
$\vec{(x,y)}*\sqrt{d^2 - r^2}=\vec{d}-\vec{(-y,x)}*r$  

Is this right?×

Comment: Right: just solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I have no idea on how to approach transposed vectors in algebra. (FYI This problem is meant to be a part of a computer script, so I can go heavy on trig and vector maths but I can't use any reasoning while solving it each time.)

Comment: I don't know what "transposed vectors" are but you must simply solve a system of two equations. Another way would be using rotations: rotate $\vec d$ by angle $\gamma$ clockwise and then multiply it by $t/d$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got some nice solution to the problem, so for anyone interested...
[An image from Wikipedia trigonometry site, that got me thinking about the solution](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Circle-trig6.svg/300px-Circle-trig6.svg.png)

[A solution in image format, because I can't post images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wctvn.png)